# Mixed word and geo search

Tags: geocoding, algolia

How can I make a search query that

1. Finds everything around a location (using `aroundLatLng` and `aroundRadius`)
2. It's biased by a word search
3. Doesn't require results to include words (e.g. they're used for relevance, but if no words match a record it is not excluded *a priori*)

?

So for example if I query for *"great view"* near `{lat: 48.8, lng: 2.3}`, it should rank by word-relevance first, then by distance, and records which doesn't match any words but are near Paris should come up anyway in the results.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure all words are not mandatory, you can use the `optionalWords` feature to consider all query words optional (beware, at least 1 will always need to match):

```
var query = "great view";
index.search(query, {
  optionalWords: query,
  aroundLatLng: '48.8,2.3',
  aroundRadius: 10000
}).then(....);
```

Then you can eventually move the `geo` criteria of the default ranking formula down, just before the `custom` one.

Comment: Yeah the problem with optionalWords is that you still need one to match... So if a record does not match any word is not included even if it's in near aroundLatLng

Comment: Yes, in that case the best is to go with 2 queries: one with the user query string and the other one with a blank query string -> then federated the results at display time.